# Move and Change dir in one go

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

When I'm moving files from the present working directory to another directory, say 'ABC', it so happens that I usually would like to go to the directory 'ABC' immediately after the move operation. Can that be done using a single command itself?

In short, is there a 'single-command' replacement for the following:

```
mv foo.dat ~/Documents/ABC/
cd ~/Documents/ABC/
```

I'm looking for something like this :

```
mv --cd foo.dat ~/Documents/ABC
```

Comment: If you object to retyping the path, you can use Meta-. to copy the last argument of the previous command to your command line.

Comment: Duplicate questions on another site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th and also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48951/create-and-move-to-a-directory-in-one-command-unix

Comment: mv foo.dat ~/Documents/ABC/ && cd ~/Documents/ABC/ will do the job if by one command you want one "line"

Comment: Thanks, @John1024 I liked the usage of '' !$ '' in the answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily make a function for it:

```
mvcd() {
    # Pass all of your parameters to "mv"
    mv "$@"

    # Shift down all positional parameters except the last one (which should be your destination)
    shift $(( $# - 1 ))

    if [[ -d "${1}" ]]; then
        # Change to your destination if it was a directory
        cd "${1}"

    else
        # Otherwise, assume the destination was a file name and extract its directory component
        cd "$(dirname "${1}")"
    fi
}
```

Using the parameter array `$@` has two big advantages:

1. You can use wildcards or globbing: `mvcd *.mp3 ./old_music/`
2. You can specify additional arguments to `mv`: `mvcd --no-clobber old.txt new.txt`

Comment: Thanks, @Mr. Llama I think I'll either make a new command like yours or try using !$ to substitute the last word of the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

An easy function would be

If you would like to go the easy way, considering MV is already a binary included in most UNIX OS you should make a function.

For example:

```
mvcd()
{
    if [ -d "$2" ]; then
        mv "$1" "$2"
        cd "$2"
        echo "Moved and changed to $PWD"
    else
        mv "$1" "$2"
        echo "Moved but couldnt change path"
    fi

}
```

This is just an easy workaround, however you should make sure you don't call it with a second parameter being a file and not a folder, that's why I use `test -d`

Comment: This breaks if you use globbing: `mvcd *.mp3 ./old_music`

Comment: @Mr.Llama tried using `mvcd "*.log" TestFolder` did the trick. However you are right it can be nasty.